# Cannot move set iterator

Tags: c++, set

What am I doing wrong:

```
set<int>::iterator beg = begin( my_set );
++beg;//<<here, no problem, as expected
beg += 3;  //error here no += operator found?!
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to advance the iterator would be using [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) or [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

```
beg = std::next(beg, 3);
std::advance(beg, 3);
```

The method of incrementing the iterator using `+=` will only work with arrays (or containers with [random access iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)) due to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me (that is that the *only* correct way it would be to use the method you've mentioned). I can do that that is beg += 5; with vector's iterator, why not with set's?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando I just edited to explain that. That will only work for contiguous containers with random access iterators

Comment: `+=` is applicable to random access iterators, not only arrays

Comment: @Piotr Skotnicki, to me it looks like inconsistency really. Why not allow += for set? Surely in set's case that would mean next(iter,3), I really don't understand why?

Comment: *"or other contiguous containers"* -- `std::deque` is not contiguous. The important distinction is that the collections are random-access, not that they are contiguous. And @Thereisnothingwecando, the reason it's not overloaded for non-random access iterators is because `operator+=` has a long tradition of being a constant time operation. But for non-random access containers, it wouldn't be. The standard committee decided that providing the operator would mislead people into thinking it was a cheap operation, so they decided not to.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley +1 Thanks, makes sense. Best Regards

Comment: @BenjaminLindley although this constraint makes somewhat difficult to write generic code where the container type differs ;(

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando Actually it is the opposite, `std::advance` and `std::next` were made so that you *could* use different container iterators, and they would all behave correctly.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: What Cory said, although I would encourage you not to blindly replace your `+` and `+=` operations with `next` and `advance`. In my own code, I intentionally use `+` and `+=`, even though I know `next` or `advance` would be more general, precisely because I don't want a function to work with non-random access iterators. If you find yourself wanting to use `next` or `advance`, strongly consider whether you actually want to be using the container you are using.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley then shouldn't you write couple of types of this function so it simply dispatches depending on type of container? I don't know but this seems like a good idea to me